# Unable to pair socket scanner

Tags: android, bluetooth, zxing, socketscan

I'm using socket scanner model 8Qi  and I'm not able to pair it with my device (moto G 5.0.2 and Samsung s5) I'm getting error code -27 and then -47.

What I have till now

- included android and core packages of Zxing library in my sample project.
- Download Socket scan 10 from google play store and configure scanner.My scanner is visible in SocketScan 10 app

Am i missing any step?? Please Help

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are not able to get the scanner to connect to your app, but it works with SocketScan10. If you are using ZXing, it should be completely separate from ScanAPI and so it's not relevant to the errors you are seeing. Did you start with SingleEntry?

Comment: @Enrico Yes i'm using SingleEntry app only

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you scan SPP Mode on page 17 of the manual before you pair it with your Android device.  It should show as an accessory rather than a game console.  I've had it try to connect as a game console and it didn't work that way.  The graphic changes when it's in the right mode.